# Nginx proxy to Azure storage

Tags: nginx, azure-storage

I am trying to setup an nginx reverse proxy for Azure blob storage. I'm using the `nginx:1.13.9-alpine` image, and I have a simple proxy_pass configured like this:

```
location /container {
  proxy_pass              https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container;
  proxy_set_header        Host account.blob.core.windows.net  
}
```

However, it doesn't quite work. A direct request to the storage account works, so I know the SAS token is good:

```
curl -v "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/file?st=2018-04-02T01%3A57%3A00Z&se=2018-04-11T01%3A57%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=<sig>"
```

But using the same token through the proxy always returns a 403:

```
curl -v "https://proxy.mydomain.com/container/file?st=2018-04-02T01%3A57%3A00Z&se=2018-04-11T01%3A57%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=<sig>"
...snip...
< HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

In the server logs I just see:

```
10.240.0.4 - - [06/Apr/2018:04:07:30 +0000] "GET /container/file?st=2018-04-02T01%3A57%3A00Z&amp;se=2018-04-11T01%3A57%3A00Z&amp;sp=rl&amp;sv=2015-12-11&amp;sr=b&amp;sig=<sig> HTTP/1.1" 403 621 "-" "curl/7.54.0" "-"
```

I've seen some conflicting advice about needing to include `$is_args`, etc, but none of it seems to work. The same nginx instance proxies several other resources through other paths, all of which work as expected. What am I missing?

**edit**

I believe this is related to encoded characters like `%2f` in the url path. Azure Storage in this case is being used as the backend for a Docker Registry, and it likes to give blobs names like `%2fdocker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/e7/e7c1ef..ced394/data`. If I add a sample blob in the container without the leading `%2f`, everything works as expected.

Comment: Why are you trying to set up this proxy? Tell us what you're trying to achieve, not just your method. Please edit your question rather than replying in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

In your default or site's config file. give blob container url as `proxy_pass` and set base url of your container as `proxy_set_header Host`

```
location /images {
        proxy_pass https://YOURACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/images;
        proxy_set_header Host YOURACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what finally worked:

```
location /files/ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    if ($request_uri ~* "/files/(.*)") {
      proxy_pass https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/$1;
    }
}
```

I have no idea why the resolver is needed, given that other locations resolve OK. It only seems to become a requirement when the `proxy_pass` command contains a variable.